# Log: Queue's awaitRelease() has been interrupted abruptly while it wasn't released byte release() method

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, rxandroidble

Below is a section of logcat which contains the message I'm occasionally seeing: `Queue's awaitRelease() has been interrupted abruptly while it wasn't released byte release() method.` The "`byte`" seems to be a typo. Searching the project for the string "`byte release`" doesn't find anything.

Where is this message coming from, and what does it mean? The program appears to work OK.

Log excerpt:

```
12-15 12:54:07.933 26145-26797/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/RxBle#ConnectionOperationQueue:  STARTED DescriptorWriteOperation(167521506)
12-15 12:54:07.938 26145-26820/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/BluetoothGatt: setCharacteristicNotification() - uuid: 00002a18-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb enable: false
12-15 12:54:07.949 26145-26820/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/RxBle#ConnectionOperationQueue:   QUEUED DescriptorWriteOperation(1053980218)
12-15 12:54:07.949 26145-26820/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/Glucometer: Unsubscribing from flushSubscription and GlucometerInteraction.
12-15 12:54:07.949 26145-26820/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/Glucometer: Sleeping for 1000MS and disconnecting from the glucometer.
12-15 12:54:07.949 26145-26820/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/AbstractBleDevice: Unsubscribed from connObservable; closing connection(?)
12-15 12:54:07.950 26145-26820/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/AbstractBleDevice: disconnect(): unsubscribing from connectionSubscription
12-15 12:54:07.952 26145-26795/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/RxBle#ClientOperationQueue:   QUEUED DisconnectOperation(939620424)
12-15 12:54:07.954 26145-26205/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/RxBle#ClientOperationQueue:  STARTED DisconnectOperation(939620424)
12-15 12:54:07.956 26145-26795/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice I/RxBle#ConnectionOperationQueue: Connection operations queue to be terminated (9C:35:83:0A:6D:F9)
12-15 12:54:07.956 26145-26256/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/BluetoothManager: getConnectionState()
12-15 12:54:07.956 26145-26256/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/BluetoothManager: getConnectedDevices
12-15 12:54:07.957 26145-26797/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice W/RxBle#ConnectionOperationQueue: Queue's awaitRelease() has been interrupted abruptly while it wasn't released byte release() method.
                                                                                                            java.lang.InterruptedException
                                                                                                                at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
                                                                                                                at com.polidea.rxandroidble.internal.serialization.QueueSemaphore.awaitRelease(QueueSemaphore.java:15)
                                                                                                                at com.polidea.rxandroidble.internal.serialization.ConnectionOperationQueueImpl$1.run(ConnectionOperationQueueImpl.java:64)
                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:422)
                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
                                                                                                                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
                                                                                                                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
12-15 12:54:07.967 26145-26256/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: 9C:35:83:0A:6D:F9
12-15 12:54:07.974 26145-26162/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=0 clientIf=6 device=9C:35:83:0A:6D:F9
12-15 12:54:07.975 26145-26162/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/RxBle#BluetoothGatt: onConnectionStateChange newState=0 status=0
12-15 12:54:07.976 26145-26797/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/RxBle#ConnectionOperationQueue: FINISHED DescriptorWriteOperation(167521506)
12-15 12:54:07.979 26145-26256/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/BluetoothGatt: close()
12-15 12:54:07.980 26145-26256/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/BluetoothGatt: unregisterApp() - mClientIf=6
12-15 12:54:07.982 26145-26205/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/RxBle#ClientOperationQueue: FINISHED DisconnectOperation(939620424)
12-15 12:54:07.984 26145-26797/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/RxBle#Executors$RunnableAdapter: Terminated.
12-15 12:54:08.950 26145-26820/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/MainActivity: Restarting scan for Glucometer in 130 seconds.
12-15 12:56:18.960 26145-26145/com.calderadev.truecareccm.truecareservice D/ReactiveBluetoothHelpers: Subscribed to glucoseScanner
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it comes from [QueueSemaphore.java](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle/blob/master/rxandroidble/src/main/java/com/polidea/rxandroidble/internal/serialization/QueueSemaphore.java). This spelling mistake has been fixed already in master.

It is nothing you should be worried about, the state of the library is cleaned up correctly. It happened because your `DescriptorWriteOperation` was blocking the semaphore when it was "abruptly interrupted" by a disconnect operation.

Comment: Is there any way for me to detect if this `QueueSemaphore.awaitRelease()` is still executing, so I can wait for it to complete? I am having trouble finding where in my source I am interrupting it, and would like to avoid adding arbitrary delays.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem. Later, I found out the reason is that the colleague in charge of this section set the BLE device automatically disconnect on schedule. To change this setting, the problem is solved.

Comment: Thanks. Where is the setting to automatically disconnect on schedule? How does it work?